# Non-unique breaks using the cut function in a constrained optimisation problem in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm having trouble using the function `cut` in an optimisation problem. I'll explain.

What I'm trying to do is separate a column from a dataframe in 10 intervals while respecting many constraints. The goal of the optimisation is to find the 11 numbers giving me the 10 intervals which will allow me to be the closest possible to a reference point. Hence why I'm using the `cut` function in an optimisation problem.

The problem is that when I try and start the algorithm I always get the same error : `Error in cut.default(pd, breaks = int_vf) : 'breaks' are not unique`. However, I set up the code so that each break point is stricly higher than the previous one (by the way i'm using the `ompr` library).

```
result <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x1, type = "continuous", lb = 0.0001) %>%
  add_variable(x2, type = "continuous", lb = x1 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x3, type = "continuous", lb = x2 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x4, type = "continuous", lb = x3 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x5, type = "continuous", lb = x4 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x6, type = "continuous", lb = x5 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x7, type = "continuous", lb = x6 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x8, type = "continuous", lb = x7 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x9, type = "continuous", lb = x8 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x10, type = "continuous", lb = x9 + 0.01) %>%
  add_variable(x11, type = "continuous", lb = x10 + 0.01) %>%
  set_objective(obj(c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11)), "min")
```

The `obj` is my objective fucntion which calls the `cut` function.

I don't get how I could have non-unique breakpoints with these parameters but there certainly is something that I am missing. If someone could enligthen me on how the `cut` function works exctacly in those circumpstances and how to get read of the error that would be of great help.

Comment: The objective must be linear. I.e. of the form `a*x1+b*x2+...`. (Probably first-year calculus course). You can't just use any function. That would make it (highly) nonlinear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and as you say my problem is not linear. When I get x1,x2,..., I need to compute the distribution of several variables in my dataset which then allow me to compute my objective function. Hence why I need to go through the ```cut``` function. Do you know if it is still possible to do using different packages maybe ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about your problem to make recommendations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.